# Get Data from Odata service with Logged in User

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have one Odata service , which is providing me the data and I am able to display this data on table. We are going to deploy this application to Launchpad. Now we have this requirement in which logged in user must get the data according to his/her login ID. So If my user ID is XXXXX , I should get the records only for XXXXX. I am unable to understand the process flow. Shall we implement the logic in Odata itself or should I get all the data and filter the model on UI, before displaying it.

Regards,
MS

Answer (score 1):

In oData itself you can access login user by sy-uname. using that user you can filter your data.

OR

In front end you can access login user by below code

```
var vUrl = "proxy/sap/bc/ui2/start_up";
var oxmlHttp = null;
    oxmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oxmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (oxmlHttp.readyState == 4 && oxmlHttp.status == 200) {
        var oUserData = JSON.parse(oxmlHttp.responseText);
        vUser = oUserData.id;
       }
    };
    oxmlHttp.open( "GET", vUrl, false );
    oxmlHttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle this in Odata only. Get User id from UI using

```
var storename = sap.ushell.Container.getService("UserInfo").getId();
```

and set it to Odata to filter and send back the results.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle such requirements in the Service level (OData level), not in the UI. 
In DPC_EXT class variable SY-UNAME gives you the logged in user. So you should filter your records by deriving more information from that.